# NSBatchUpdateRequest converting string to unicode

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using `NSBatchUpdateRequest` to update my core data content. I use the following code:

```
    NSBatchUpdateRequest *req = [[NSBatchUpdateRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Mostvisited"];
    req.propertiesToUpdate = @{@"newsCategory":self.newsCategory,@"newsCommentsCount":self.newsCommentsCount,@"newsDate":self.newsJalaliDate,@"newsID":self.newsID,@"newsLead":self.newsLead,@"newsPhotoLink":self.newsPhotoLarge,@"newsTitle":arr,@"newsType":self.newsType,@"timeStamp":[NSDate date]
                               };

    req.resultType = NSUpdatedObjectIDsResultType;
    NSBatchUpdateResult *result = (NSBatchUpdateResult *)[context executeRequest:req error:nil];
    NSLog(@"objects update:%@",result.result);
```

All the objects passed as update are `NSArray` containing Arabic `NSString`. Surprisingly when i fetch the content of the core data after the update all i get is Unicode strings not the Arabic ones.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are Unicode by default, if you wanted them to be Arabic you would probably have to convert them using CFStringTransform. There is a good article detailing how this can be achieved at NSHipster.

Essentially, it's this call:

```
CFStringTransform(mutableString, nil, kCFStringTransformToLatin, Boolean(0))
```

More info:
[CFStringTransform](http://nshipster.com/cfstringtransform/)